# Regular Expression Pattern for five consecutive numerics only

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need a pattern to extract five consecutive numerics only.

ExampleA: 123456789 dsadss**12345**@3_- 1d22d333

ExampleB: **12345**_ 2d2d2 aaa2222a

ExampleC: 2d2jj ddd_@**12345**

Wanted output: **12345**

or

(not number: "espace"; "letter"; "symbols:,-& etc")**(5 consecutive numbers)**(not number: "espace"; "letter"; "symbols:,-& etc")

or

**(5 consecutive numbers)**(not number: "espace"; "letter"; "symbols:,-& etc")

or

(not number: "espace"; "letter"; "symbols:,-& etc")**(5 consecutive numbers)**

Tried these:

```
  (1)strPattern = "(((\s|\D|\W)(\d{5})(\s|\D|\W))|((\d{5})(\s|\D|\W))|((\s|\D|\W)(\d{5})))"
  (2)strPattern = "\d{5}"
  (3)strPattern = "(\s|\D|\W)(\d{5})(\s|\D|\W)"
  (4)strPattern = "\D(\d{5})\D"
```

(3) won't work with ExampleB

(2) won't work with ExampleA

(1) is the best I could get but it won't work in few cells.

Comment: What's the next character in Example C?  What's the previous character in Example B?  To make it easiest, Every example needs a clear start/stop.

Comment: You may use [`(?:^|\D)(\d{5})(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/UJ4RZ1/1) and grab `match.Submatches(0)`.

Comment: `(\d{5}?)` is the pattern for exactly 5 numeric digits.

Comment: In ExampleB there is no character, the cell starts with 12345, in ExampleC it ends with 12345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{5})(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJ4RZ1/1).

The `(?:^|\D)` will match either the start of string or any char other than a digit, `(\d{5})` will capture 5 digits into Group 1 and `(?!\d)` will make sure the next char is not a digit.

Sample code:

```
Dim re, targetString, colMatch, objMatch
Set re = New regexp
With re
 .pattern = "(?:^|\D)(\d{5})(?!\d)"
 .Global = True              ' Same as /g at the online tester
End With
targetString = "123456789 dsadss12345@3_- 1d22d333"
Set colMatch = re.Execute(targetString)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
  Debug.Print objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0)
Next
```

Comment: This (?:^|\D)(\d{5})(?!\d) worked really well, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to use SubMatch without an object? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @ehdgur Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. `.SubMatches` is a property of the `Match` object.

Answer (score 3):

## RegEx Cheat Sheet

Not really an answer on it's own but I think this excellent summary is worth it (and easier share here!)

**Click images to view full-size.**
[image]
[image]

Comment: took me years to figure out regex... but its actually quite simple.  Experiment by pasting your sample text into [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) and trying different combinations.

Answer (score 1):

This passed all of the tests outlined in OP:

```
((?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d))
```

Full match will only be 5 consecutive digits surrounded by anything except for a digit

PROOF IS IN THE PUDDING:

https://regex101.com/r/Oz2aeR/1

Comment: proof it works: https://regex101.com/r/Oz2aeR/1...  (also, it's identical to the previous answer!)

Comment: not identical as we pull different matches! but tyvm for link that is cool

Comment: OPs full match brings back string char mine is 100% straight up the consecutive digits